# Laravel Foreign key constraint incorrectly informed

Tags: laravel

Não consegui encontrar onde está o erro na minha migration, sinceramente.

Alguém aí consegue entender por que estou tendo o seguinte erro:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table
>   `imobiliaria`.`#sql-2d3c_21` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is
>   incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `imoveis` add constraint
>   `imoveis_capa   _foreign` foreign key (`capa`) references `imagens`
>   (`id`) on delete no action on update no action)

Migration:

```
   <?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateImoveisTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Schema table name to migrate
     * @var string
     */
    public $set_schema_table = 'imoveis';

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     * @table Imoveis
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('imoveis');
        Schema::create($this->set_schema_table, function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('tipo_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('nome');
            $table->float('valor');
            $table->integer('cidade_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('atributo_id')->unsigned();
            $table->text('descricao')->nullable();
            $table->integer('finalidade')->nullable();
            $table->float('area');
            $table->integer('quartos');
            $table->integer('banheiros');
            $table->integer('garagens');
            $table->integer('suites');
            $table->string('bairro')->nullable();
            $table->integer('capa')->unsigned()->nullable();

            $table->foreign('capa')->references('id')->on('imagens')
                ->onDelete('no action')
                ->onUpdate('no action');

            $table->foreign('tipo_id')
                ->references('id')->on('tipos')
                ->onDelete('no action')
                ->onUpdate('no action');

            $table->foreign('cidade_id')
                ->references('id')->on('cidades')
                ->onDelete('no action')
                ->onUpdate('no action');

            $table->foreign('atributo_id')
                ->references('id')->on('atributos')
                ->onDelete('no action')
                ->onUpdate('no action');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
     public function down()
     {
       Schema::dropIfExists($this->set_schema_table);
     }
}
```

Migration das imagens:

```
 <?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateImagensTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Schema table name to migrate
     * @var string
     */
    public $set_schema_table = 'imagens';

    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     * @table Imagens
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create($this->set_schema_table, function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('urlImagem', 45)->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
     public function down()
     {
       Schema::dropIfExists($this->set_schema_table);
     }
}
```

Comment: Tem como colocar a migration imagens completa?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic coloquei

Comment: A ordem que estava errada, ou seja, primeiro tem que criar a tabela de imagens, depois criar a tabela de imoveis, porque, a de imoveis precisa que imagens exista

Comment: Mas a ordem estava certa ainda, na hora da execução ele executava primeiro a de imagens, depois de imóveis.

Comment: No meu teste foi isso...